# Python pandas change duplicate timestamp to unique

Tags: python, duplicates, pandas

I have a file containing duplicate timestamps, maximum two for each timestamp, actually they are not duplicate, it is just the second timestamp needs to add a millisecond timestamp.
For example, I am having these in the file,

```
....
2011/1/4    9:14:00
2011/1/4    9:15:00
2011/1/4    9:15:01
2011/1/4    9:15:01
2011/1/4    9:15:02
2011/1/4    9:15:02
2011/1/4    9:15:03
2011/1/4    9:15:03
2011/1/4    9:15:04
....
```

I would like to change them into

```
2011/1/4    9:14:00
2011/1/4    9:15:00
2011/1/4    9:15:01
2011/1/4    9:15:01.500
2011/1/4    9:15:02
2011/1/4    9:15:02.500
2011/1/4    9:15:03
2011/1/4    9:15:03.500
2011/1/4    9:15:04
....
```

what is the most efficient way to perform such task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup

```
In [69]: df = DataFrame(dict(time = x))

In [70]: df
Out[70]: 
                 time
0 2013-01-01 09:01:00
1 2013-01-01 09:01:00
2 2013-01-01 09:01:01
3 2013-01-01 09:01:01
4 2013-01-01 09:01:02
5 2013-01-01 09:01:02
6 2013-01-01 09:01:03
7 2013-01-01 09:01:03
8 2013-01-01 09:01:04
9 2013-01-01 09:01:04
```

Find the locations where the difference in time from the previous row is 0 seconds

```
In [71]: mask = (df.time-df.time.shift()) == np.timedelta64(0,'s')

In [72]: mask
Out[72]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
6    False
7     True
8    False
9     True
Name: time, dtype: bool
```

Set theose locations to use an offset of 5 milliseconds (In your question you used 500 but could be anything). This requires numpy >= 1.7. (Not that this syntax will be changing in 0.13 to allow a more direct `df.loc[mask,'time'] += pd.offsets.Milli(5)`

```
In [73]: df.loc[mask,'time'] = df.time[mask].apply(lambda x: x+pd.offsets.Milli(5))

In [74]: df
Out[74]: 
                        time
0        2013-01-01 09:01:00
1 2013-01-01 09:01:00.005000
2        2013-01-01 09:01:01
3 2013-01-01 09:01:01.005000
4        2013-01-01 09:01:02
5 2013-01-01 09:01:02.005000
6        2013-01-01 09:01:03
7 2013-01-01 09:01:03.005000
8        2013-01-01 09:01:04
9 2013-01-01 09:01:04.005000
```

Answer (score 1):

So this algorithm should work very well... I'm just having a hell of a time with numpy's datetime datatypes.

```
In [154]: df
Out[154]: 
                  0
0  2011/1/4 9:14:00
1  2011/1/4 9:15:00
2  2011/1/4 9:15:01
3  2011/1/4 9:15:01
4  2011/1/4 9:15:02
5  2011/1/4 9:15:02
6  2011/1/4 9:15:03
7  2011/1/4 9:15:03
8  2011/1/4 9:15:04


In [155]: ((dt.diff() == 0) * .005)
Out[155]: 
0    0.000
1    0.000
2    0.000
3    0.005
4    0.000
5    0.005
6    0.000
7    0.005
8    0.000
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

And the idea is to add those two together.  Of course, one is `datetime64` and the other is `float64`.  For whatever reasons, `np.timedelta64` doesn't operate on arrays?  Anyway if you can sort out the dtype issues that will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming** - *as you have shown in your example* that they are sequential:

```
lasttimestamp = None
for ts = readtimestamp(infile): # I will leave this to you
   if ts == lasttimestamp:
      ts += inc_by  # and this
   lasttimestamp = ts
   writetimestamp(outfile, ts) # and this to
```

Comment: This is not going to be very efficient.

Comment: It ought to be nearly as fast as the disk access while still ensuring that only the duplicates get changed.