# Python pandas change variable number of duplicate timestamps to unique

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, time-series

This is related to a previous question: [Python pandas change duplicate timestamp to unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159675/python-pandas-change-duplicate-timestamp-to-unique), hence the similar name of this one.

The additional requirement is to handle multiple duplicates per second and space them out evenly between second boundaries, i.e.

```
....
2011/1/4    9:14:00
2011/1/4    9:14:00
2011/1/4    9:14:01
2011/1/4    9:14:01
2011/1/4    9:14:01
2011/1/4    9:14:01
2011/1/4    9:14:01
2011/1/4    9:15:02
2011/1/4    9:15:02
2011/1/4    9:15:02
2011/1/4    9:15:03
....
```

Should become:

```
....
2011/1/4    9:14:00
2011/1/4    9:14:00.500
2011/1/4    9:14:01
2011/1/4    9:14:01.200
2011/1/4    9:14:01.400
2011/1/4    9:14:01.600
2011/1/4    9:14:01.800
2011/1/4    9:14:02
2011/1/4    9:14:02.333
2011/1/4    9:14:02.666
2011/1/4    9:14:03
....
```

I am stumped on how to deal with the variable number of duplicates.

I thought along the lines of a `groupby()`, but couldn't get it right.  I was thinking that this is a common enough use-case to have been solved already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted datetime column to `timedelta[ms]`. But problem was with too big numbers, so first I convert year to [epoch time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090869/why-is-1-1-1970-the-epoch-time) - `2011 - 1970`. Then I counted differences, which were added to column one: `df['one'] = df['one'] - df['new'] + df['timedelta'].` Then timedeltas in miliseconds as integers was converted to timedeltas and last was added years `2011 - 1970`.

```
#                 time
#0  2011-01-04 09:14:00
#1  2011-01-04 09:14:00
#2  2011-01-04 09:14:01
#3  2011-01-04 09:14:01
#4  2011-01-04 09:14:01
#5  2011-01-04 09:14:01
#6  2011-01-04 09:14:01
#7  2011-01-04 09:15:02
#8  2011-01-04 09:15:02
#9  2011-01-04 09:15:02
#10 2011-01-04 09:15:03
#time    datetime64[ns]

#remove years for less timedeltas
df['time1'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: x - pd.DateOffset(years=2011-1970))
#convert time to timedeltas in miliseconds
df['timedelta'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time1']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'ms')
df['one'] = 1
#count differences by groupby and transforming mean/sum
m = lambda x: (x.mean()) / x.sum()
df['one'] = df.groupby('time')['one'].transform(m)
#cast float to integer
df['new'] = (df['one']*1000).astype(int)
#need differences by cumulative sum
df['one'] = df.groupby('time')['new'].transform(np.cumsum)
#column cumulatice sum substracting differences and added timedelta
df['one'] = df['one'] - df['new'] + df['timedelta']
#convert integer to timedelta
df['final'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['one'],unit='ms')
#add removed years
df['final'] = df['final'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x) + pd.DateOffset(years=2011-1970))
#remove unnecessary columns
df = df.drop(['time1', 'timedelta', 'one', 'new'], axis=1)
print df
#                  time                   final
#0  2011-01-04 09:14:00 2011-01-04 09:14:00.000
#1  2011-01-04 09:14:00 2011-01-04 09:14:00.500
#2  2011-01-04 09:14:01 2011-01-04 09:14:01.000
#3  2011-01-04 09:14:01 2011-01-04 09:14:01.200
#4  2011-01-04 09:14:01 2011-01-04 09:14:01.400
#5  2011-01-04 09:14:01 2011-01-04 09:14:01.600
#6  2011-01-04 09:14:01 2011-01-04 09:14:01.800
#7  2011-01-04 09:15:02 2011-01-04 09:15:02.000
#8  2011-01-04 09:15:02 2011-01-04 09:15:02.333
#9  2011-01-04 09:15:02 2011-01-04 09:15:02.666
#10 2011-01-04 09:15:03 2011-01-04 09:15:03.000
```